# stop previous audio from playing when starting a new one

Tags: unity, c#, audio

I created a dialogue system with audio it works perfectly fine unless you start skipping the voice lines so then it all becomes a mess with all of the voice lines overlapping is there a way to make it so when you go to the next audio line the previous one stops playing?

[Example of what is happening](https://youtu.be/C4zdHixLXSk)

as you can see in the video you can switch the text just fine and it doesn't show the previous one but for the audio, it just transforms into a jumbled mess, is there a way to fix this or to at least make it so people cant go to the next line until they finish hearing the current one?

DialogueManager Script:

```
public class DialogueManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public Door1Animation doorAnimation;

public Text nameText;
public Text dialogueText;
public Text changeText;

public AudioManager Sound;

public Animator textBoxAnimation;

public Queue<string> sentences;

public Queue<string> voiceLines;

void Start()
{
    sentences = new Queue<string>();
    voiceLines = new Queue<string>();
}

public void StartDialogue (Dialogue dialogue)
{
    textBoxAnimation.SetBool("Open", true);
    
    changeText.text = ("Aperte R para continuar");

    nameText.text = dialogue.name;


    sentences.Clear();

    voiceLines.Clear();


    foreach (string sentence in dialogue.sentences)
    {
        sentences.Enqueue(sentence);
    }

    DisplayNextSentence();

    foreach (string voiceLine in dialogue.voiceLines)
    {
        voiceLines.Enqueue(voiceLine);
    }

    PlayNextLine();
}

public void DisplayNextSentence()
{
    if (sentences.Count == 1)
    {
        changeText.text = ("Aperte R para fechar");
    }

    if (sentences.Count == 0)
    {
        EndDialogue();
        return;
    }

    string sentence = sentences.Dequeue();
    dialogueText.text = sentence;
}

public void PlayNextLine()
{
    if (voiceLines.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    string voiceLine = voiceLines.Dequeue();
    Sound.Play(voiceLine);
}

public void EndDialogue()
{
    Debug.Log("End of conversation");
    doorAnimation.openDoor = true;
    textBoxAnimation.SetBool("Open", false);
}
}
```

AudioManager Script:

```
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public Sound[] sounds;



void Awake()
{
    foreach (Sound s in sounds)
    {
        s.source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        s.source.clip = s.clip;

        s.source.volume = s.volume;

        s.source.pitch = s.pitch;

        s.source.loop = s.loop;

    }

}

private void Start()
{
    Play("BackgroundMusic");
}

public void Play (string name)
{
    Sound s = Array.Find(sounds, sound => sound.name == name);
    s.source.Play();
}
}
```

Just the part of the interaction code so you can go to the next line/audio:

```
    public void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        
        PersonInteract();
        buttonInteract();

    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
    {
        FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().DisplayNextSentence();
        FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().PlayNextLine();
    }
}
```

Inspector view of the dialogue manager:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty trivial. Just remember which audio source you played most recently, and stop it before you play a new one.

```
AudioSource _lastPlayed;

public void Play (string name, bool cancelOnNextSound)
{
    if (_lastPlayed != null && _lastPlayed.isPlaying) {
        _lastPlayed.Stop();
    }

    Sound s = Array.Find(sounds, sound => sound.name == name);
    s.source.Play();

    if (cancelOnNextSound) {
        _lastPlayed = s.source;
    }
}
```